# How do I make a container div only overflow horizontally without using "display:inline-block" for its inner divs?

Tags: javascript, css, html, overflow

I'm trying to create `<div>`s within another `<div>` at the click of a button. When the button is clicked, a new inner `<div>` is created (within the outer `<div>`) with a unique id. Each inner `<div>` also has a random `margin-top` CSS value. All this works but I would like to make the outer `<div>` **only scroll horizontally**. Therefore, the inner `<div>`s all have to be created inline. However I cannot use `display:inline-block` for the inner `<div>`s because that removes the random `margin-top` functionality.

(Credit to [user totymedli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1494454/) for the code help)

#### HTML

```
<button id="button1">Add box</button>
<div id="outer"></div>
```

#### CSS

```
#outer {
position:absolute;
white-space:nowrap;
height:118px;
overflow:auto;
width:100%;
padding:2px;
}

.box{
float:left;
width:48px;
height:48px;
background-color:#000;
margin-left:5px;
}
```

#### Javascript

```
var number = 0;

document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", pressButton, false);

function pressButton() {
    ++number;
    makeDiv(number);
};

function makeDiv(x) {
    var innerDiv = document.createElement("div");
    outer.appendChild(innerDiv);
    innerDiv.className += " box";
    innerDiv.setAttribute("id", "innerDiv" + x);
    innerDiv.setAttribute("style", "margin-top:" + Math.floor(Math.random()*51) + "px;");
};
```

Here is the [working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/T929z/1/).

As you can see, creating new inner `<div>`s works and each of them has a random `margin-top`. How do I make the outer `<div>` scroll horizontally and prevent the inner `<div>`s from breaking to the next line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, you can use `inline-block`, just add `vertical-align:top` and it will work as expected.

[**UPDATED EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/wSA3a/)

It's worth noting that the default value of `vertical-align` is `baseline`; that's why the `margin` didn't *seem* to be taking effect.

```
.box{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    width:48px;
    height:48px;
    background-color:#000;
    margin-left:5px;
}
```

If, for some reason, you are insistent on floating the elements (which I don't recommend), you would simply have to increase the width of the parent element to therefore contain the children elements.

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly and I can now sleep soundly tonight :D

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

Instead of  `inline-block` ,you can also use `inline-table`

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/2r3mG/)**

```
.box{
    display: inline-table;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    background-color: #000;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```